# How Can I Do? CSS Flexbox Layout Question

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, frontend

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUzsT.png

How can I make this structure with flex without using div using at minimal code?

my html;

```
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use `div`?

Comment: @ttoshiro I'm sensitive about this. I really don't want to use it.

Comment: @ttoshiro example: footer is not correct. https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PoPwPbE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example you gave in the comments above, you could try something like this, which uses no `<div>` tags:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

* {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  flex: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 25%;
}

.main {
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 75%;
}

.article {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">Header</header>
<aside class="sidebar">Nav</aside>
<main class="main">
  <article class="article">Content</article>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</main>
</div>
```

---

It would frankly be a lot more organized to use a `<div>` element to call for classes that specify containers. If you want to do that, try:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.display {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 75px;
}

.nav {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 75%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row, .navbar {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>header</h1>
</div>

<div class="display">
  <div class="nav">
    <h1>Nav</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Content</h1>
      <p>Context text</p>
    </div> 
    <div class="footer">
      <h1>Footer</h1>
      <p>Footer text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are very kind. Using div is not suitable for my construction.

Comment: Fair enough. I edited my answer to add an example that only uses `<div>` once -- check the first example!

Comment: oh, im sorry. 
i am reviewing immediately.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not use any div in the body.

Comment: I see. I removed the `<div>` tag and replaced it with an `<main>` and `<article>` tag. It should work fairly similarly. Try the first example again!

Comment: Can we do it outside the footer main?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the footer's width to span the entire page?

Comment: apart from each other I want it that way;
<main></main>
<footer></footer>
****outside****